# Using python generics and inheritance

Tags: python, generics, inheritance, keyword-argument

I need to implement a bunch classes, that all need to do the same modification to the parent class. As a skilled C++ programmer, I would look for a template class. But this needs to be implemented in Python. Here I am a rookie. I found the "Generic" and has constructed this example to show the core in my problem. The real program is somewhat more complicated(using ReportLab to generate PDF documents). I need to subclass to benefit from the class framework, which leads me into trying to implement a Generic using inheritance.

The problem is that cannot understand how I can pass argument to the "super" class, which here I try to make a Generic.

First attempt:

```
super().__init__(*argv, **kwargs)
```

Second attempt:

```
super(G, self).__init__(*argv, **kwargs)
```

Third attempt:

```
T.__init__(*argv, **kwargs)
```

Here is the complete example:

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

class A():
    def __init__(self, i : int):
        self.i = i

    def draw():
        print(self.i)

class C():
    def __init__(self, s : str):
        self.s = s

    def draw():
        print(self.s)

T = TypeVar('T')


class G(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, *argv, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*argv, **kwargs)
        
    def draw():
        # Here is some special going to happen
        super().draw()
        
        
gA = G[A](5)        
gB = G[B]('Hello')

gA.draw()
gB.draw()
```

The output that I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 34, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/typing.py", line 729, in __call__
    result = self.__origin__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 28, in __init__
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have understood Python generics wrong. A Generic, say `Generic[T]`, makes the `TypeVar` `T` act as whatever you provide the instance with.

I found this [page](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html) to be very useful with learning Generics.

Comment: Thanks for the link looks promising..

Answer (score 1):

`typing.Generic` is specifically for type annotations; Python provides no runtime concept equivalent to either:

1. Template classes, or
2. Function overloads by parameter count/type

The latter has *extremely* limited support from [`functools.singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch), but it only handles the type of one argument, and the runtime type-checking is fairly slow.

That said, you don't *need* a template-based class or a polymorphic inheritance hierarchy here; Python is perfectly happy to call `draw` on anything that provides a method of that actual name. The code you're writing here can just do:

```
a = A(5)
b = B('Hello')

a.draw()
b.draw()
```

with no use of `G` needed.

Comment: It is the ReportLab library that forces me into wanting this template like construct. I need to create a new subclass that does the exact same as super but just rotate the canvas beforehand. I'll have to see if I can find another way around the problem. Thanks for your clarifications.

Comment: @PaulGroskopf: Would it be practical to write a mix-in class that both `A` and `B` inherit from, and have both `A` and `B` invoke `super().draw()` before doing the rest of their work? If `super()` is used consistently, even a diamond inheritance hierarchy would work (for classes `Mix`, `A(Mix)`, and `B(Mix)`, and `C(A, B)` where each `draw` invokes `super().draw()` before doing their own thing [LIFO invocation order] would end up calling `C.draw`,`A.draw`,`B.draw`,`Mix.draw` in that order, but the LIFO order would do the work `Mix` first, then `B`, then `A`, then `C`).

Comment: That looks like how I ended up doing it. I made a common super class. And then added a parameter to control what I needed.